# How to fill a nested (Parent/Child) list using two DataTables using LINQ

Tags: c#

I am new with Linq and c#.
I am working to fill two nested list using two Datatables.There is a StudentList is the parent list. Each student has a GradeList for each course. I can get Two Datasets as DataTables from Database, one is the Student, the other is the Grade. In the Grade class has a studentID that can link with the Student. How Can I populate the StudentList?

```
    public class Student
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public List<Grade> GradeList { get; set; }

}
  public class Grade
{
    public string CourseID { get; set; }
    public string CourseTitle { get; set; }
    public decimal CourseGrade { get; set; }
    public string studentID { get; set; }
}
```

//below is the code

```
DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];  //students
        DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[1]; //Grades

        studList = (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
                        select new Student()
                        {
                            ID = dr["ID"].ToString(),
                            FirstName = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString(),
                            LastName = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString(),
                            GradeList = (from DataRow gdr in dt1.Rows as IEnumerable
                                       //  where gdr["studentID"] == ID
                                         select new Grade() 
                                         {

                                             CourseID = gdr["COURSEID"].ToString(),
                                             CourseTitle = gdr["COURSETITLE"].ToString(),
                                             CourseGrade = Convert.ToDecimal(gdr["COURSEGRADE"]),
                                             studentID = gdr["STUDENTID"].ToString()
                                         }.ToList()

                                         )


                        }).ToList();
```

I am expecting to fill studList.
Thanks a lot

Comment: How to put a where clause? also, there is an Error CS1061 'Grade' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no accessible extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'Grade' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
studList = 
    (from DataRow dr in dt.Rows
     select new Student()
     {
         ID = dr["ID"].ToString(),
         FirstName = dr["FIRSTNAME"].ToString(),
         LastName = dr["LASTNAME"].ToString(),
         Email = dr["EMAIL"].ToString(),
         GradeList = 
             (from DataRow gdr in dt1.Rows as IEnumerable
              where gdr["studentID"] == dr["ID"]
              select new Grade() 
              {
                  CourseID = gdr["COURSEID"].ToString(),
                  CourseTitle = gdr["COURSETITLE"].ToString(),
                  CourseGrade = Convert.ToDecimal(gdr["COURSEGRADE"]),
                  studentID = gdr["STUDENTID"].ToString()
              }).ToList()
      }).ToList();
```

The first `ToList()` needed to be after the closing parenthese, and the `where` condition for `GradeList` needs to reference a variable outside of the object initializer, because the `Student` object isn't fully constructed yet.